# Loop through list of data frames

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have several data frames. In each data frame there is a column called Current.Net.Price . I want to change the column names to different names.
Therefore I have two lists:

```
Names <- c("name1","name2","name3","name4","name5")
dfList <- list(df1,df2,df3,df4,df5)
```

I tried something like this:

```
i=1
for (df in dfList) {
  names(df)[names(df) == "Current.Net.Price"] <- Names[i]
  i<-i+1
}
```

But when I call

```
View(dfList$df2)
```

the column is still named Current.Net.Price

Could someone help me please? :)

Comment: for clarification: each data.frame in dfList has got a column named "Current.Net.Price" and each of those column names is to be replaced with a *different* name obtained from `Names`, right?

Comment: Is it me, or does this sound like an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem)? What are you ultimately trying to solve/achieve?

Comment: But if this is really what you want: `df[,Names(i)] <- df$Current.Net.Price`. Easier to check if you make a new column and no overwriting of original data.

Comment: Well, it is about some price lists of different months. In each is a price and I want to rename them because at the end I would like to merge all data frames. But your solution also works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this simple but similar example.
It's all about how you access your dfList to exctract info about the data.frames's names.

```
 # data frames
dt1 = data.frame(x = 1:3,
                     y = 5:7)

dt2 = data.frame(x = 1:4,
                     z = 5:8)

dt3 = data.frame(y = 1:10,
                 x = 21:30)


Names = c("A","B","C")
dfList <- list(dt1,dt2,dt3)


for (i in 1:length(dfList)) {

  names(dfList[[i]])[names(dfList[[i]])=="x"] = Names[i]

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe when you loop like that (loop over items in a list/vector), the original objects don't get updated. E.g.,

```
l <- 1:5
for (i in l) {
  i <- 3
}
l
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

The following works for me.

```
df1 <- data.frame("x" = rnorm(5),"Current.Net.Price"=1:5)
df2 <- data.frame("x" = rnorm(5),"Current.Net.Price"=1:5)
df3 <- data.frame("x" = rnorm(5),"Current.Net.Price"=1:5)
df4 <- data.frame("x" = rnorm(5),"Current.Net.Price"=1:5)
df5 <- data.frame("x" = rnorm(5),"Current.Net.Price"=1:5)

Names <- c("name1","name2","name3","name4","name5")
dfList <- list(df1=df1,df2=df2,df3=df3,df4=df4,df5=df5)


for (i in 1:5) {
  names(dfList[[i]])[names(dfList[[i]]) == "Current.Net.Price"] <- Names[i]
}

sapply(dfList, colnames)

#      df1     df2     df3     df4     df5
# [1,] "x"     "x"     "x"     "x"     "x"
# [2,] "name1" "name2" "name3" "name4" "name5"
```